# Apple TV Markup Language formTemplate multiple Fields

Tags: tvml

I just start with Apple TV Markup Language and my client require login in one step, but if i try to add two fields in one form only first field is displayed, my code is:

```
<document 
  data-view="LoginScreen">
   <formTemplate>
      <banner>
        <img src="${CONFIG.configURL}/${CONFIG.splashScreen}"
      width="1920" height="1080" />
        <description>Enter email</description>
      </banner>
      <textField name="username">username@test.ro</textField>
      <banner>
        <img src="${CONFIG.configURL}/${CONFIG.splashScreen}"
      width="1920" height="1080" />
        <description>Enter password</description>
      </banner>
      <textField text="******" secure="true" name="password"></textField>
      <footer>
        <button id="login">
          <text>Login</text>
        </button>
      </footer>
   </formTemplate>
</document>
```

Any suggestions ?

Thank you, and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: I am facing same issue. Please post your answer when you solve your problem.

Comment: Hi @Dhruv, of course but right now i just implemented login in two steps because seems tvml do not have this feature.

Comment: Can you please share code of two steps? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Dhruv, sorry for this huge delay, here is the code http://pastebin.com/x66CEHeK , you must do refectoring on it, sorry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.